# Getting exception on saving an XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-sdcard

I am developing an Android App and in that i am trying to download XML file from this URL `http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml` and trying to save this file into my sd card.

I want to download file when button is clicked. So, I use following code on my Button Click..

```
try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml");

        //create the new connection

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!

        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file

        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the

        //sd card.

        File SDCardRoot = new File("/sdcard/"+"XML_folder/");

        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename

        //which we want to save the file as.

        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"webservice.xml");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file

        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        //variable to store total downloaded bytes

        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 

        {

        //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card

        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

        //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded

        downloadedSize += bufferLength;

        int progress=(int)(downloadedSize*100/totalSize);

        //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe

        //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }

        //close the output stream when done

        fileOutput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

As I have used `try and catch` its catching an Exception and showing me this message `data.gov.in`.

So, what I do now.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using AsyncTask to run the snippet you posted?

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?